# Function to return true if two letters are either both upper or both lower case not working, c++

Tags: c++, char, boolean, uppercase, lowercase

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char myChar_1 = 'a';
char myChar_2 = 'b';
char checkChar(char myChar_1,char myChar_2){
    if ((isupper(myChar_1) && isupper(myChar_2)) || (islower(myChar_1) && islower(myChar_2))) {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }

}

int main()
{
    cout << checkChar(myChar_1, myChar_2);
```

}

The output is an upside-down question mark. Would be great if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong. Niko

Comment: Why does your function return a `char`?

Comment: you are declaring a function with keyword as char and returning a boolean true false value......

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your return type should be `bool`. You're returning `true` and `false` as `char`s and then outputting that character. When converting from `bool` to an integral type, `true` is converted to 1 and `false` is converted to 0. So you're printing out `char`s with values of 0 or 1.

Comment: ah, thanks! what a stupid mistake....